# Add output attribute to parent component for dynamically generated angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am adding dynamic components to div in angular using `createComponent` method

```
let coolComponentRef = this.formControls?.createComponent(CoolComponent);
```

Child components site inside parent components and there are few events which i want to send to parent components.
I do this using `@Output` on child component.

```
@Output()
propertiesEvent = new EventEmitter<Properties>();
```

and its usage is

```
<cool-component (propertiesEvent)="itemSelected($event)"></cool-component>

full example:
<div id="formControls" #formControls>
<cool-component (propertiesEvent)="itemSelected($event)"></cool-component>
</div>
```

However, my use case is that the child elements are added dynamically using `createComponent`, so how can i add `(propertiesEvent)` to dynamically created component.

**EDIT**: Found this link usefull [Angular4 communication between child dynamically created component to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553150/angular4-communication-between-child-dynamically-created-component-to-parent), is there other simpler way exists?

Comment: You can either (as the linked question states) subscribe to the `EventEmitter` prorammatically right after creating the component, or you could write a shared service that the dynamically created components can interact with if needed.

Comment: I imagine you can use a service.